# XMLHTTP Inticated URL

Tags: excel, vba, url

I have a list of URLs in the excel worksheet and would like to check the page status to check whether URL is active or not.
I wrote macro but it doesn’t work. Can somebody take a look at the code and let me know what I am doing wrong? 
Below is the code I wrote:

```
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim column_number: column_number = 9
For i = 1 To 200
    strURL = sh.Cells(i, column_number)
    sh.Cells(p) = CallHTTPRequest(strURL)
Next
Function CallHTTPRequest(strURL)
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    objXMLHTTP.Open "HEAD", strURL, False
    objXMLHTTP.send
    Status = objXMLHTTP.Status
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
    CallHTTPRequest = Status
End Function
```

Thank you in advance.
Nara.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Can you be specific?

Comment: Here is a compile error: expected End Sub and marked (strURL) on the 5th code line. Sorry, I am a beginner on VBA. How can I upload an example file to here?

Comment: You're missing an `End Sub` after the `Next`.